# What are reasons to use return as a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

while I was going through concepts related to JavaScript functions, I came up with problem which I'm unable to figure it out. I use following codes i.e one with **return as a function** and the other as a simple function as follows

```
function plus(a, b) {
   return(
       console.log(a+b),
       console.log(this),
       console.log(arguments)
   )
}
plus(4,5);
```

and

```
function plus(a, b) {      
       console.log(a+b),
       console.log(this),
       console.log(arguments)
}
plus(4,5)
```

But when I run both I'm not able to figure it out since both results same in console. So I just want to know when should I use return as function.? and what is its main purpose? I've seen answers here but those related to return entire function or objects but didn't find specific answer to **return as a function**. So please help me in it.

Comment: You don't return a function here, you return `undefined` in both cases.

Comment: @zerkms That's `return` "_as a function_" not "_return a function_", by which the OP must mean calling `return` with a `()` enclosed list of statements.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski okay. And a list of "expressions"

Comment: `console.log(a+b, this, arguments)`, no `return`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes that's what I exactly meant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return(
       console.log(a+b),
       console.log(this),
       console.log(arguments)
   )
```

statement means:

`return` the argument that is represented by `(...)` expression. Here parentheses is not a part of a `return` keyword syntax, but is a standalone operator used in conjunction with operator `,`.

The `(1, 2, 3)` expression after evaluating returns the value of the last expression.

In your case it's `console.log(arguments)` which returns `undefined`.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: Would `arguments` not be the `arguments` Array-like Object?

Comment: @PHPglue not sure what you mean

Comment: You say it's `undefined` when it would be `a` and `b` in an Array-like Object.

Comment: @zerkms how console.log(arguments) undefined when it gives array as PHPglue mentioned?

Comment: @PHPglue: `console.log` call returns `undefined`

Comment: @Kishore Kumar Korada: it prints the arguments to the console, but returns the `undefined` value.

Comment: Ok, all `console.log` calls return `undefined` but will still print to the console. You `return` something in a function when you want something from the function.

Comment: @zerkms How could you do that D are you an admin or what?

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada how could I do what?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
function plus(a, b) {
   return(
       console.log(a+b),
       console.log(this),
       console.log(arguments)
   )
}
```

is an equivalent of this:

```
function plus(a, b) {
   var r = (
       console.log(a+b),
       console.log(this),
       console.log(arguments)
   );
   return r; 
}
```

or simply this (EDIT, but is wrong, see zerkms comment ):

```
function plus(a, b) {
   var r = 
       console.log(a+b),
       console.log(this),
       console.log(arguments);
   return r; 
}
```

where `,,` is an expression - compute all parts delimited by commas with result of last expression.

Comment: "or simply this:" --- unless it's syntactically incorrect.